# Less than date y/m/d

Tags: php

I have Id's I went to check if they have expired, they're in y/m/d format so I get todays date in that format and it comes out incorrect.

How can I compare

2021/03/15

With 2021-12-25

The dashes versus slashes doesn't seem to matter, so I think it's the month

Todays date is parsed as a date, the other is a string from an SQL statement array

```
$utz = new DateTimeZone($_SESSION['timezone']);
$dt = new DateTime(null, $utz);
$today = $dt->format('Y/m/d');

while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
        if ($myrow['id1_expiry'] < $today) { 
            printf ("<tr bgcolor=#FD5D5D>.... }else{
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please, show us your attempt.

Comment: Parse both into DateTime objects and then you can compare easily, and the original format is irrelevant

Comment: I tried variables that equate to 'if 2021-12-25 < 2021/03/15' change a background colour, and it changed.

Comment: @ADyson can I do that for an array field?

Comment: It's not clear what part an array plays in this? It sounded like you had two strings? Maybe clarify with a code sample and sample data

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @ADyson added some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the `DateTime` objects using comparison operators.

You could use a formated date to create a [new DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object, for [accepted format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

```
$utz = new DateTimeZone($_SESSION['timezone']);
$date = new DateTime(null, $utz);

while ($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (new DateTime($myrow['id1_expiry'], $utz) < $date) { 
        echo 'expired';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't find the ones that are really expired

Comment: Please check this [demo](https://3v4l.org/5lE3a). As you can see, the date comparison works as expected. Maybe you have an issue with timezone ?

Comment: The demo doesn't look like my code, it doesn't show me how I can parse the 2nd date

Comment: If the date from database is `2021-12-25`, `new DateTime($sqldate)` will works.

Comment: So, you don't need `$today = $dt->format('Y/m/d');` but just compare `$dt` with `new DateTime($sqldate)`.